# use system-wide environment variable when running a service with ansible

Tags: ansible, systemctl

I would like to use `ansible` to deploy a configuration which, as a final step, (re)start a service. That service needs environment variables which are defined in my host machine (the one in which the playbook is stored). In order to pass those env var to my target machine I tried to add the `environment` arguments to ansible `service` directive by doing the following:

```
  - name: start service
    service:
      name: my_service
      state: restarted
    environment:
      OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL: "{{ lookup('env','OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL') }}"
      OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL: "{{ lookup('env','OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL') }}"
      CLIENT_SECRET: "{{ lookup('env','CLIENT_SECRET') }}"
```

However this fails in the sense that those variables are unknown when the service is started. The only way I could find to solve that problem was to modify my playbook by doing the following:

```
  - name: set some env vars systemctl
    shell: |
      systemctl import-environment OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL CLIENT_SECRET
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
    environment:
      OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL: "{{ lookup('env','OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL') }}"
      OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL: "{{ lookup('env','OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL') }}"
      CLIENT_SECRET: "{{ lookup('env','CLIENT_SECRET') }}"

  - name: start my service
    service:
      name: my_service
      state: restarted
```

is that the *correct* way to proceed ?

NB: being quite new with ansible, I did not play with `role` stuff for which I would like to stay away at the moment.

**Systemctl configuration file:**

```
[Unit]
Description=my_service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Environment="PATH=/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/start_myservice.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Service to be run:**

```
#/bin/bash

echo "${CLIENT_SECRET}"
echo "${OAUTH2_AUTHORIZE_URL}"
echo "${OAUTH2_TOKEN_URL}"
```

Answer (score 2):

In a systemd service unit, you can use the `EnvironmentFile` directive to pass environment variables in a more convenient way than with the `Environment` one. It also allows for sharing variables across services, if needed.

You can use ansible to install the file containing the environment variables with a simple `copy` or using a `template`, e.g. in `/etc/<service>/environment`.

That way you don't need to set those variables everytime you deploy. Only once when you setup the service for the first time, and when those settings need to change.

Also, from what I understand, using `import-environment` means systemd will pass the variables you import to all units, which may not be what you want. Especially for the `CLIENT_SECRET` one.

Comment: thanks a lot. I read about the EnvironmentFile option. It seems that it allows, like  the Environment option, to set environment variables but not to use existing ones. Not succeeding in finding the right solution to my problem is probably the sign that I am wrong in what I try to do.